# Where is the layout file in my ListView?

Tags: android

I am new to android and i am confused about something. I have created a simple ListView, here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList<String> listItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
            listItems.add("List Item #"+i);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

This correctly displays the list items on the screen, but here is my question: I have no xml files, no layouts in my project and i do not use setContentView function here. So why is this code working? How can it be displayed even though there is no xml files or layouts?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` as the layout, which provides a `TextView` for you to work with. This is a layout provided by Android for simple lists of text.

If you want to make a more complex layout, you will/can define your own layout.

Comment: Thank you, i thought that that is just for styling issues but i get it now.

Comment: Also, you would normally need to use `setContentView()`, but in this case `ListActivity` is handling all that for you.

Answer (score 2):

Android ships with default containers for list items.

As the name suggests, `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` belongs to the **android.R** package and not to your app's resources.